# Beyond one-hot encoding for LSTM model in Keras

Tags: neural-network, keras, lstm, one-hot-encoding

I have an LSTM model in Keras for categorical classification (20 possible categories). In many cases, my data can fit multiple categories.

Obviously, my current model uses one-hot encoding and fits on that - that gives me accuracy and validation rates in the 50-60% but I want to improve that by comparing how the model does against the top 3 categories that the algorithm chooses.

Right now, I use Keras with categorical_crossentropy. I presume that this checks to see if the label is the top match and bases the accuracy on that matching. How can I modify the fit/training of the model to allow the labeled category to be in the top 3 (or top X-number) of matches for the accuracy score?

Comment: Are you talking about multi-label categorical classification then? If yes this will change how you think.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for top-k categorical accuracy. This is actually implemented in keras, but you might want to change the k, which can be done with partial function. This is the related [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51951358/keras-how-to-get-top-k-accuracy).

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing multilabel, you should do `binary-crossentropy` and `sigmoid` in a final layer. You must score your labels separately. Here's an [example](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2018/05/07/multi-label-classification-with-keras/).